# C# My computer calculates floats wrongly while in other computers, it works

Tags: c#

I have been following a course online for c# and I am stuck on this code.
Here is the code:

```
using System;

namespace ProgrammingAssignment2
{
    // IMPORTANT: Only add code in the section
    // indicated below. The code I've provided
    // makes your solution work with the 
    // automated grader on Coursera

    /// <summary>
    /// Programming Assignment 2
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        // x and y coordinates for points
        static float point1X;
        static float point1Y;
        static float point2X;
        static float point2Y;

        /// <summary>
        /// Programming Assignment 2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">command-line args</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // loop while there's more input
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input[0] != 'q')
            {
                // extract point coordinates from string
                GetInputValuesFromString(input);

                // Add your code between this comment
                // and the comment below. You can of
                // course add more space between the
                // comments as needed

                 float deltaX = point2X - point1X;
                float deltaY = point2Y - point1Y;
                float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.Pow(deltaY, 2));

                float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(deltaX, deltaY);
                angle = (angle * 180) / (float)Math.PI;

                Console.WriteLine(distance + " " + angle);

                // Don't add or modify any code below
                // this comment
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts point coordinates from the given input string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">input string</param>
        static void GetInputValuesFromString(string input)
        {
            // extract point 1 x
            int spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 1 y
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1Y = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 2 x
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point2X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // point 2 y is the rest of the string
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            point2Y = float.Parse(input);

            #region Unfortunately, Mono doesn't have a Split method!
            //string[] values = input.Split(' ');
            //point1X = float.Parse(values[0]);
            //point1Y = float.Parse(values[1]);
            //point2X = float.Parse(values[2]);
            //point2Y = float.Parse(values[3]);
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

When the somebody else runs the code and inputs '5 5 4 4' it is supposed to output '1.414214 -135' which is what is supposed to output but when I do it, it outputs '1,4142135 -135' I have no idea why it is like this. Please help.
but

Comment: Your PC is set to a region that uses comma instead of period as the decimal separator. Check your regional settings.

Comment: @BradleySmith I changed my region to America and yes now it uses '.' instead of ',' but that is not the problem. It calculates wrongly. My output is '1.4142135 -135' but it should output '1.414214 -135' (The last 2 digits of the first output)